# How can I get an animated SVG to start "drawing itself" sooner?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to create a loading animation with ONLY html & css that looks like an ekg readout.  I have it working but I want it to start redrawing sooner (right now it completely disappears and I'd like it to start drawing the before it finishes "undrawing"

```
<head>

    <style>
    body {
  background-color: #fff;
}



.path {
  animation: draw 2.2s infinite ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation: draw 2.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}


 @keyframes draw {
   from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
 }
     to { stroke-dashoffset: 50}
}

        @-webkit-keyframes draw {
   from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
 }
     to { stroke-dashoffset: 50}
}

    </style>
    </head>
<div class="bg">  
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="670" height="236" viewBox="0 0 670 236">

  <path class="path" stroke="#ca6728" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="500" stroke-dashoffset="610" fill="none" d="M0,80.9h20.6c0.5,0,1.4-0.2,1.8-0.5L38,70.1
        c0.5-0.3,1.2-0.3,1.6,0l12.7,9.4c0.4,0.3,1.3,0.6,1.8,0.6l13.3,0c0.6,0,1.2,0.4,1.5,0.9l6.2,11.3c0.3,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.5-0.1l4.4-90.8
        c0-0.5,0.1-0.5,0.1,0l6.9,102.1c0,0.5,0.2,0.6,0.4,0l7-22.4c0.2-0.5,0.7-1,1.3-1l16.1,0c0.5,0,1.3-0.3,1.8-0.7L129,66.4
        c0.4-0.4,1.1-0.3,1.5,0l13.3,13.1c0.4,0.4,1.2,0.7,1.7,0.7l20.1,0,"/>



  </svg>
</div>

    </html>
```

JS Fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/jzvenice/4sLw9ag9/

Comment: cloning the whole thing and having the two overlapping would be too weird? Just asking, it seems hackish to me, but it could work if the second one would have a timeout for starting up.

Comment: If I tried that, would I copy the .path class and call it .path2 and delay the start?

Comment: something like that. Let me know how it works! Maybe make a jsfiddle psot, too so we can look at the same thing running.

Comment: This should be close to the desired effect? https://jsfiddle.net/4sLw9ag9/1/

Comment: @Shikkediel that's pretty close but I don't want to use javascript

Comment: There's no need, it is disabled and just a little helper to get the length of the path only once when setting it up - outside of general functionality. After that is can be discarded and doesn't have to be in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think a similar effect can be achieved by playing with the stroke-dasharray values :

https://jsfiddle.net/4sLw9ag9/2/

```
...

stroke-dasharray="391 300" stroke-dashoffset="0"

....

@keyframes draw {
from {
stroke-dashoffset: 691;
}
to {
stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

...
```

Only the first value is exact (length of the path is 391 pixels), it was detected with a line of JavaScript that is commented out and not needed for further functionality. The other value can be adjusted for what comes across best visually.

Edit - previously deleted the answer but it seems more relevant than a comment. So don't mind me undeleting with a minor update.

Comment: Thank you!  The stroke-dasharray was the missing element I was looking for.